# WinObjC building project errors

Tags: winobjc

I download the `WinObjC` files for GitHub and following all the steps. When I try to build the project, I have this problem (using Visual Studio Community 2015)

These are the two errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning MSB3245 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "XamlCompositorCS". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. WOCCatalog (WOCCatalog\WOCCatalog)  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1819


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'OpenGLES.lib'   WOCCatalog (WOCCatalog\WOCCatalog)  D:\WinObjC-master\samples\WOCCatalog\WOCCatalog.vsimporter\WOCCatalog-WinStore10\LINK

1
```

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Open included solution in  WinObjC/build/build.sln

Select Build / Build Solution

Comment: What does that mean exactly?

Comment: `build.sln > Build > Build Solution` results in 3965 build errors: `Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported` and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to download the prebuilt SDK (look under "Releases" in github) or, per the above comment:

> Open included solution in WinObjC/build/build.sln
>   Select Build / Build Solution

Comment: Can you expand on this answer to make it more valuable than the answer you are already referencing?

Answer (score 0):

1.Download the latest release version

2.open ...\WinObjC\build\build.sln

ps:If using virtual machine(Such as PD),make sure all files storing in Windows folder(such as c:\somewhere)  instead of  Mac folder (such as \\Mac\Home\Desktop)

3.vs 2015 update1 may alert installing wp8/8.1 tools.

4.Building your Solution( Select Build/Build Solution).